# first_or_create with a validation with scope is giving "email has already been taken" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, scope

The Attendee model has the following validation:

```
   validates :email, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false, allow_blank: true, allow_nil: true, scope: :customer_id }
```

And on this line:

```
    attendee = Attendee.where(email: params['email'], customer: customer).first_or_create!
```

when there is a record that matches both conditions, the email and the customer, I am getting the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Email has already been taken)
```

The funny thing is that when I run the command on the rails console, it works. But not on my app.

What am I missing? How do I debug this?

Edit: adding SQL queries

```
BEGIN

Customer Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers" WHERE "customers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 4883], ["LIMIT", 1]]

SELECT 1 AS one FROM "attendees" WHERE LOWER("attendees"."email") = LOWER($1) AND "attendees"."customer_id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["email", "some@email"], ["customer_id", 4883], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

on the rails console

```
 Attendee Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "attendees".* FROM "attendees" WHERE "attendees"."email" = $1 AND "attendees"."customer_id" = $2 ORDER BY "attendees"."id" ASC LIMIT $3  [["email", "some@email.com"], ["customer_id", 4883], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Comment: can you share the  sql queries of where calls on your server log and rails console?

Comment: Maybe there's a difference in the email's letter case? In that case, the "find first" part would fail to retrieve the record and the "create" part would fail too because of the `case_sensitive: false` validation.

Comment: just added .downcase to the email param and it worked. You were right! Thanks!